# How to compare two sheets in different work books and highlight the difference in 2nd sheet?

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub compare2sheetsex() 'and highlight the diffrence
    Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook, sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet
    Set wb1 = Workbooks(InputBox("enter b1"))
    Set wb2 = Workbooks(InputBox("enter b2"))
    Set sh1 = wb1.Sheets(InputBox("enter s1"))
    Set sh2 = wb2.Sheets(InputBox("enter s2"))
    rcount = sh1.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    ccount = sh1.UsedRange.Columns.Count
    Dim r As Long, c As Integer
    For r = 1 To rcount
        For c = 1 To ccount
            If sh1.Cells(r, c) <> sh2.Cells(r, c) Then
                sh2.Cells(r, c).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
            End If
        Next c
    Next r
    Set sh1 = Nothing
    Set sh2 = Nothing
End Sub
```

Q:I tried to compare 2 sheets in different workbooks but i am unable to execute the code above.

Comment: what happens when you try to execute the above code? Do you get an error? Or just unexpected results?

Comment: I unable to execute,Yes i am getting an error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aside from some undeclared variables (using Option Explicit will prevent this, and typos in variable names), your code works fine for me with some minor modifications:

```
Option Explicit
Sub compare2sheetsex() 'and highlight the diffrence
    Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook, sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet
    Dim rCount As Long, cCount As Long
    Set wb1 = Workbooks(InputBox("enter b1"))
    Set wb2 = Workbooks(InputBox("enter b2"))
    Set sh1 = wb1.Sheets(InputBox("enter s1"))
    Set sh2 = wb2.Sheets(InputBox("enter s2"))
    rCount = sh1.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    cCount = sh1.UsedRange.Columns.Count
    Dim r As Long, c As Integer
    For r = 1 To rCount
        For c = 1 To cCount
            If sh1.Cells(r, c) <> sh2.Cells(r, c) Then
                sh2.Cells(r, c).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
            End If
        Next c
    Next r
    Set sh1 = Nothing
    Set sh2 = Nothing
End Sub
```

Screenshot:

[image]

The only thing I notice is that both workbooks **must** be open for this code to work.  If you are entering a filename & path, you'll need to use the `Workbooks.Open` method with your input boxes, e.g.:

```
Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open(InputBox("enter b1"))
Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(InputBox("enter b2"))
```

Otherwise, you don't have any error-handling with your inputboxes so it's possible that if you receive `Subscript out of Range` errors, that you did not correctly input the Workbook or Worksheet names to the inputboxes.

Comment: Sorry, I am not able to execute the above code perfectly. I am getting "Subscription out of range" error

Comment: **WHICH LINE RAISES THE ERROR?** And, are **BOTH** workbooks open before you run the macro?

Comment: I am getting Run time error 9
"Subscription out of range" after entering book1 name

Comment: Then it is either one of two things (both are effectively the same thing): you mistyped the name or the specified workbook is not currently open.

Comment: Yes David...The sheet name was case sensitive.Thanks for your help :)